# Creating test data in web application?

Tags: testing, selenium, web-applications, automation, qtp

I have a web application which has flow of 10 pages to create a custom. I have to create 20 customer daily for testing purpose which
is frustrating and time taking process.

I know there are QTP  or selenium scripts which are designed
for automation and create quick data. But i am not familiar with automation script. Is there a web tool that can help me out here?

Comment: You can try to use JMeter to create your users. It has the posibilty to record http traffic. Or you can use Selenium IDE to record. But Selenium is going to be slow compared to JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many ways. You can create an automation script to create customers and use task scheduler.  You can also execute sql query to add customers. As Andreas said you can also use Jmeter. Choice is yours which one suites you the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using Selenium IDE. First, record creation of one user. Then follow instructions in this [link](http://unmesh.me/2012/12/04/data-driven-testing-with-selenium-ide/) to parameterize the data entered. Run the script with different data when needed.